# Edit DataGrid column name dynamically and Remove some columns

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

I bind some data to a datagrid in c# like this:

```
DataGrid1.ItemsSource = Logs.Where(elem => elem.Name == ActiveName);
```

But i want to change some of the columns names that appears on datagrid and hide some other columns.

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to Set AutoGenerateColumns to false and specify your columns in DataGrid.Columns

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False">
     <DataGrid.Columns>
          <DataGridTextColumn Header="Serial Number" Binding="{Binding serialnumber}" />
          ...
     </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```